# Why does a type of all types including itself create a paradox in Martin-Löf type theory?

Tags: type-theory, paradoxes

In Per Martin-Löf (1998) "An Intuitionistic Theory of Types" in G Sambin and JM Smith (eds) *Twenty-five years of constructive type theory* Clarendon Press (original work written 1972 but unpublished), at p. 133, Martin-Löf says that a universe $V$ which is the type of all types, including itself, so $V : V$ (or in his notation, $V \in V$) is inconsistent because of Girard's paradox.

Martin-Löf goes on to give a proof that where a type $U$ is defined as the type of all orderings without infinite descending chains, there is an ordering on $U$ itself which both has and does not have infinite descending chains, which is paradoxical. I understand the proof itself, but the problem is that I do not understand why the proof depends on $V$ being the type of itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Girard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_U#Girard's_paradox) for a brief overview and references.

Comment: See also [Extensions of Type System, Polymorphism, Paradoxes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#ExteTypeSystPolyPara)